# Angular and .net core. Signalr. Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, websocket, signalr, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to establish a websocket connection for server-client real-time updates. My controller is able to retrieve data without any problems. However, I get this error when establishing connection for signalR with the server:

`Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200`

Here is my client side signalR service code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as signalR from "@aspnet/signalr";
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { DiagramsService } from './diagrams.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SignalRService {

  constructor() { }
  public data: DiagramsService[];
  private _hubConnection: signalR.HubConnection
  _url = environment.API_URL;

  public startConnection = () => {
    this._hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                            .withUrl(this._url + '/Statistics/OPDailyCount',{
                              skipNegotiation: true, 
                              transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
                            })
                            .build();
    this._hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => console.log('Connection started'))
      .catch(err => console.log('Error while starting connection: ' + err))
  }
  public addTransferChartDataListener = () => {
    this._hubConnection.on('transferchartdata', (data) => {
      this.data = data;
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

My signalR service is consumed by this component:

```
constructor(private svcDiagrams : DiagramsService, private svcSignalR : SignalRService, private http : HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.svcDiagrams.OPDailyRegistration().subscribe(data => {
      this._rawData = data;
      this.value = +this._rawData.value;
      this.units = 'Current OPD Registration Count';
    });
    
    this.svcSignalR.startConnection();
    this.svcSignalR.addTransferChartDataListener();   
    this.startHttpRequest();
  }

  private startHttpRequest = () => {
    // this.http.get(environment.API_URL+'/Statistics/OPDailyCount')
    //   .subscribe(res => {
    //     console.log(res);
    //   });

    this.svcDiagrams.OPDailyRegistration().subscribe(data => {
      this._rawData = data;
      this.value = +this._rawData.value;
      this.units = 'Current OPD Registration Count';
    });
  }
```

Here is my startup.cs configurations:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: AllowedOrigin,
                                  builder =>
                                  {
                                      builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                                        .AllowCredentials();
                                  });
            });
            services.AddSignalR();
```

My endpoints:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapHub<StatsHub>("/Statistics/OPDailyCount");
            });
```

This is my server side controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("OPDailyCount")]

        public async Task<AdmissionStatistics> GetOPDailyRegistrationCount()
        {
            var timerManager = new TimeManager(() => _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("transferchartdata", _repoStatistics.GetOPDailyRegistrationCount()));
            return await _repoStatistics.GetOPDailyRegistrationCount(); 
        }
```

I do get a 101 response status code on request. If that helps [101 status code on websocket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vU8jK.png)

I have been trying to apply the fixes I found on the web, nothing seems to fix mine, though.

Comment: You shouldn't use a controller to handle incoming SignalR calls on the server. You need a `Hub` instead. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-5.0). Hub methods do not need MVC attributes like `HttpGetAttribute` or `RouteAttribute`. To set a hub method name, use the [`HubMethodNameAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.hubmethodnameattribute?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: If you do not specify the allowed transports `transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets` on client side, does it work?

Comment: The websocket is working now; I used a strongly typed hub with or without the transport type. However, I am getting a new error for disposed connection when I call the method using a timer.